# Java interface with constructor in implementation class

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a rather basic question about interfaces, something I'm rather new too. I typically would instantiate my class with an overloaded constructor. I'm now trying to use interfaces and wondering how I would populate my constructor. Would I just use something like setSomeMethod(arguement1, arguement2) in my interface to populate my attributes?

I'd also like to note I'm using "Tapestry5" framework with service Injection. Example

```
public class Main {

    @Inject
    private Bicycle bicycle;

    public Main() {
         //Not sure how to pass constructor variables in
         this.bicycle();
    }

}
```

Interface

```
public interface bicycle {
   public void someMethod(String arg1, String arg2);
}
```

Impl Class

```
public class MountainBike implements bicycle {

   private String arg1;

   private String arg2;

   public MountainBike() {
       //Assuming there is no way to overload this constructor
   }

   public void someMethod(String arg1, String2 arg2) {
       this.arg1 = arg1;
       this.arg2 = arg2;
   }

}
```

Then how do you handle extended classes? I'm not sure how to populate the extended class constructor.

```
public class MountainBike extends BicycleParts implements bicycle {

   private String arg1;

   private String arg2;

   public MountainBike() {
       //Assuming there is no way to overload this constructor
       //Not sure where to put super either, but clearly won't work here. 
       //super(arg1);            
   }

   public void someMethod(String arg1, String2 arg2) {
       this.arg1 = arg1;
       this.arg2 = arg2;
       //Assuming it doesn't work outside of a constructor, so shouldn't work 
       //here either.   
       //super(arg1);
   }

} 

public class BicycleParts {

    private String arg1;

    public void BicycleParts(String arg1) {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your `bicycle` method should be declared with a return type:

```
public void someMethod(String arg1, String arg2);
```

Interfaces define a contract for methods and not how objects are instantiated. They can also define static variables.

To use `someMethod` in your MountainBike constructor, you could make the call in the constructor:

```
public MountainBike(String arg1, String arg2) {
   someMethod(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Wrt, your question on extending the class, the super statement must appear as the very first statement in the constructor i.e.:

```
public class MegaMountainBike extends BicycleParts implements bicycle {

   public MegaMountainBike() {

      super("Comfy Saddle");
      // do other stuff
   }
```

Comment: I should probably clarify the question a bit more. I'm actually using Tapestry, "java framework" which uses @Inject to handle class instantiation. You typically access the class through the interface which is where I'm becoming lost and the reason for this basic java question. BTW, I didn't write this in the IDE, so the return type was just an accident. Fixed

Comment: You mean Tapestry + Spring? If so then you are not strictly bound to using interfaces.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I altered my question/example to better reflect my issue. It seems my basic knowledge of interface/class/extend was accurate, but Tapestry's use of service Inject is losing me. I need to Inject my Bicycle class in order to Inject other services into the Bicycle class such as Hibernate Session etc. Do you have any knowledge on this? Thanks Reimeus

Comment: Yes I've certainly used Spring, Tapestry not so much. I think these areas might deserve a new question posting.

Comment: I agree, however you did answer my initial question very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused. Java the language defines constructors and methods. Constructors have special restrictions and cannot be put in an interface, and are implicitly called whenever you do a `new` statement. Since constructors cannot be placed in interfaces, the common practice is to use factory methods instead.